# How to insert/update an item in a specific column of a dynamic table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, html-table

I have a dynamic table as of [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yvonnezoe/545H4/1/) As you can see, I have a column for "Status" which i hope to get status reply through this done(function()). This is what i've tried http://jsfiddle.net/yvonnezoe/nbrSR/1/

I set the id for that column as `id="status_' + rowID` because each row will be different. Then, i find each column of each row by setting a variable

```
eachStatus = $row.find('td:nth-child(5)').attr('id');
```

After that, i posted that to a python function and it will get a reply of either `on` or `off` (for now). In this Fiddle, it won't work because the python function and the real system aren't here. I just want to find out if i'm doing it correct by finding that column and do an `.append` to show the status? Well, if it is appended to a new div, the `on` and `off` can be displayed. But for this one, it never shows up in the table. Why and how should i do it? Will it be updated as well since I'm doing a setInterval, looping every 5 seconds?

```
    $.post('/request', {
    inputText: fbNum,
    key_pressed: fbType.toString()}).done(function (reply) {
    if (reply == "on") {
        $('#status_table tr #status_' + eachStatus).append("on ");
    } else {
        $('#status_table tr #status_' + eachStatus).append("off ");
    }
    });
```

FYI, you have to select an option, key in a number, check the checkbox and press "monitor". It will loop every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#status_table tr #status_' + eachStatus).append("on ");
```

should be

```
$('#status_table tr #' + eachStatus).append("on ");
```

instead because `eachStatus` already included `status`.

you may want to do an `.empty()` before the `.append()` so that new status can replace the previous one.